# Storing Arrays to use over multiple triggers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that creates multiple arrays.  I create a trigger so this script every 5 minutes until 2 values are the same.  Total running time is 50 minutes.  (Pulling various data from over 400 Spreadsheets)

Instead of putting the contents of the array into the Spreadsheet on every run, is it possible to store the arrays somewhere and add to them with each new trigger?  Then I could insert the data once instead of multiple times.

The only library I've come across for Google Script is to share functions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You can use the [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)

Be sure to check the [Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) as depending on the size of your array, it may be over the limit.

Each property can be 9KB in size and the total amount in all properties would be 500KB

You can set and get properties like this:

```js
var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();

documentProperties.setProperty('DAYS_TO_FETCH', '5');
scriptProperties.setProperty('SERVER_URL', 'http://www.example.com/MyWeatherService/');
userProperties.setProperty('DISPLAY_UNITS', 'metric');

var server_url = scriptProperties.getProperty('SERVER_URL');
Logger.log(server_url);
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'm struggling to get JSON to work with a 2D array to create the string for this, but I have started another query for that.  Thanks again.